error to fetch the secrets when we have the all admin right on eks cluster
Error loading resources
An unknown error occurred while communicating with the API. Try refreshing the page and reattempting. If the error persists, submit feedback using the feedback button on the bottom of the page. Explain the action you were trying to perform, and we'll fix it as soon as possible.
why this error we are getting or how to resolve this?
